# Is there a way i can protect myself from DDOS attacks?

Tags: router, security, denial-of-service, safe-browsing

I got my IP spoofed somehow and how? Its because i visited a site which has a ip grabber and then a redirect to the site and my router is ADB and it has firewall but i don't think it won't help so i wanted to change my ip but i can't find my MAC address because it's nowhere in the menu. is my router still safe from DDOS? I hope so. Also my PC's are clean by scanning with Malwarebytes and some other software.
Update: This is the photoshop pic i made [My Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gACck.png)

Comment: Also here's the link but it will need to be translated as im living in Lithuania https://www.teo.lt/press/14058 Also after i checked my ip it showed the wrong location where i was living in which showed Teo's HQ or something but it didnt show my home

Comment: @xiong-chiamiov I dont have any server or shares going on. Also my dad decided not to power cycle the router and the modem because it might not able to connect with new ip but i think hes lying. I think firewall is safe to use but i wont turst it anyway but my router

Answer (score 0):

> I got my IP spoofed somehow

How did you come to this conclusion?

> and how? Its because i visited a site which has a ip grabber and then a redirect to the site

What is an "ip grabber", and what do you mean by "a redirect to the site"?

> and my router is ADB and it has firewall but i don't think it won't help

Yes, a firewall can help mitigate a denial of service attack by filtering out incoming packets.

> so i wanted to change my ip but i can't find my MAC address because it's nowhere in the menu.

Why do you need to know your MAC address to change your IP?  For most ISPs, you simply need to power cycle your modem.

---

A firewall can help protect from DDoS attacks by dropping the attack packets before they get to the target system.  However, this is almost certainly unrelated to your situation.

Unless you're running an externally-facing server on your home network, you don't have a service that can be denied.

What have you read or heard that caused you to become concerned about being a target of a DDoS attack?

Comment: ip grabber is like the way you get ips by getting someone to visit the site and taking it to another page like google url shorner but it shows ips and someone got my ip like that

Comment: i think the small box is where i got my network to work but when i read the article it said to turn off any other devices that give network access but i think another way of power cycle is 1h to completly get a new ip i asked others and there were lairs saing to turn off for a month or weeks which will help but people might be dissapointed offline

Comment: I dont have any network or server stuff going on its just for browsing and using our tv's beacuse thats what my isp uses

Comment: like this article right here http://www.labnol.org/tech/power-cycle-modem-router/23412/ is saying to turn off my modem but i will turn it off once everyone is not using the wifi or tv's

Comment: My dad is saying power cycling the adb router will give a new ip but i wont have access to the internet but i think hes just preventing me from doing that he might be lying

Comment: It sounds to me like you're fine and should stop worrying about this.

Comment: youre right, electronicwiz1 is also saying that on twitter